# Как заменить ссылку на странице не используя JavaScript

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть вопрос от начинающего - как заменить текст ссылку во фрейме не используя `JavaScript`?
Есть сайт - `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe`. В левом фрейме надо заменить ссылку.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\TestTaskResources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'container')]")).getText().replace("https://www.w3schools.com","https://www.bing.com");
```

Имеем кусочек кода, который должен его заменять, но ничего не происходит при выполнении. Как заставить код заменить ссылку? Как кликнуть на кнопку RUN на этой странице? Не могу распознать, кто из них имя кнопки для обращения...

Answer (score 0):

Метод `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement#getText` возвращает тип `java.lang.String`. То есть Вы получаете текст элемента и пытаетесь заменить ссылку внутри полученого текста.

`Selenium` не предоставляет прямых методов изменять `DOM` структуру `HTML` страницы. Если Вы все же хотите это сделать, то это возможно только через `JavaScript`.

Нажать на кнопку возможно выполнив метод `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement#click` на необходимом элементе.

```
WebElement element =
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Run »')]"));
element.click();
```

Comment: проблема в том, что я JavaScript не владею от слова совсем, поэтому хотелось максимально избежать его на данном этапе. если, как я вас поняла, избежать JavaScript в данной ситуации невозможно, то как максимально простыми методами и с минимально возможным его участием решить имеющуюся проблему?